# How to find the first local maxima in a NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I've been looking all over on the internet, but I cannot find out how to do this without a for loop + if statement. Let's say that I have this as my array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 0, 1, 2, 366, 367])
```

I want to find out to find out the first highest value (regardless if there is another higher value in the future), which in this case would be `365`. This is how I would do it without using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 0, 1, 2, 366, 367])

for element in range(a.shape[0]-1):
    if a[element+1] < a[element]:
        first_max = a[element]
        break

print(first_max)
# 365
```

Is there a way to do this using a numpy function?

Comment: Dupe is a way more complicated question without the short-circuiting requirement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is taking the first differences, find the first negative value and obtain its index using `argmax`:

```
a[(np.diff(a) < 0).argmax()]
# 365
```

Though depending on the scenario, a generator and shortcircuiting in the first match might be better:

```
next(v0 for i,(v0,v1) in enumerate(zip(a[:-1], a[1:])) if v0>v1)
# 365
```